# Generic word for top and bottom

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a programmer and sorry if this sounds stupid.

If I have to specify the same value for both the right and the left property of something, I usually refer it as the **SIDE** property. Is there a similar generic word to use for a value for both the top and the bottom property?

Examples:

1. "The rectangle has 3 pixels left and 3 pixels right margin" = "The rectangle has 3 pixels side margin."
2. "The image is 40 pixels high and 40 pixels wide" = "The image size is 40 pixels."

Comment: Well, you could always use "vertical extremes".  But why not just say "top and bottom"?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a left and right property? Is this a technical concept or do you literally mean, for example, "John has a left hand and a right hand'? If the latter then please can you give a complete sentence showing how you would use the term? (You can leave a blank where the word should go)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK here is an example : "the rectangle has 3 pixels left and 3 pixels right margin" - "The rectangle has 3 pixels side margin" .... another example : "the image has 40 pixels height and 40 pixels width" - "the image is of 40 pixels size"

Comment: If no single word fits, what seems likey, you may refer to "horizontal sides" and "vertical sides".

Comment: I'm confused.  Why do you want to describe something cryptically rather than just use a straight-forward description?

Answer (score 0):

You give the following examples :

> 1. "The rectangle has 3 pixels left and 3 pixels right margin" - "The
>      rectangle has 3 pixels side margin" ....
> 2. "The image has 40 pixels height and 40 pixels width" - "The image is
>      of 40 pixels size"

1. I would change the summary as follows:

*The rectangle has 3-pixel side margins.*

2. I would change the summary to:

*The image is 40 pixels square.*

The problem is that neither of these seem to cover your original question. I imagine this would be:

3. "The rectangle has 3 pixels top and 3 pixels bottom margin"

Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Please don’t answer duplicates on the duplicate itself. If you wish to add another answer, then please do so on the original.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest equivalent to the (vertical) *Side* that I can think of is **Horizontal**.  I reckon you can make a case for it as an identifier with a value of either 'top' or 'bottom'.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/horizontal):

> parallel to, in the plane of, or operating in a plane parallel to the horizon or to a baseline.

EDIT: to give credit to @Graffito - I hadn't seen your comment when I posted.