# Left and Right are "Sides"; Front and Rear are "Ends"; Top and Bottom are...?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, hypernyms

I'm looking for a fitting word in the context of design/engineering. We have long structural members that go in an assembly and we need to be able to describe them based on their orientation and location.

EDIT: I'm looking for a word that makes sense in the following context:
[image: Positions Image]

EDIT (CONT'D): Someone putting this thing together in the real world should be able to pick up a flange labeled "[word for top-and-bottom] flange" and confidently put it in the right place.

We have an appropriate word for each orientation:

- Members oriented front-to-rear: Longitudinal members
- Members oriented left-to-right: Lateral members
- Members oriented top-to-bottom: Vertical members

However, I'm stumped for one of the words when it comes to location:

- Members located on the front or rear: End members
- Members located on the left or right: Side members
- Members located on the top or bottom: ??? members

Let me give a few usage examples. These are some examples of how we might name members in an assembly:

- Vertical Side Flange (a vertical flange located on the sides)
- Vertical End Flange (a vertical flange located on the ends)
- Lateral End Flange (a lateral flange located on the ends)
- Lateral ??? Flange (a lateral flange located on the top and bottom)
- Longitudinal Side Flange (a longitudinal flange located on the sides)
- Longitudinal ??? Flange (a longitudinal flange located on the top and bottom)

Another way to describe the positions is using the "plural" sense:

- The longitudinal extremes are the "Ends"
- The lateral extremes are the "Sides"
- The vertical extremes are the... ???

As a usage example, we also might put a note to the following effect on a drawing:

- "Repeat on both sides"
- "Repeat on both ends"
- "Repeat on both ...???"

Ideally, I'm looking for a word that can work in both singular plural and contexts, like "end/ends" and "side/sides" do.

We have such fitting words for the left-to-right and front-to-back extremes of something... I find it hard to believe that the English language has no fitting word for the vertical extremes of something. If it really doesn't, I would be strongly in favor of making up one...

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Generic for top and bottom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279340/generic-word-for-top-and-bottom) (Note: 'vertices' are the apexes or corners.)

Comment: Would ***Surface*** work?

Comment: @NigelJ thanks for pointing me to a similar post. I did find several posts with a similar question but none of them had the same engineering-context nuance that I'm looking for, or they had answers that don't work for my needs (like "vertical").

Comment: @RogerSinasohn thanks for the reply, surface is very close... but sounds odd for my usage. "Surface Flange" doesn't naturally imply "Top and/or Bottom Flange". Good suggestion, though.

Comment: Perhaps it will lead you or someone else to a better answer.

Comment: Is 'extremities' any use ?

Comment: Could it be 'poles' (polar members)?

Comment: Take a look at [how space is dealt with](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf) in English and other languages; "Space" is the second of [Fillmore's 6 Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments, still not quite what I'm looking for. I edited the post and added an image that should help clarify what I'm after. I'm looking for a word that would be intuitive for a weld/fitter putting this thing together out in the shop. Thanks all for the suggestions so far, keep them coming.

@JohnLawler, I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: You could distinguish them by terming them 'topside flanges' and 'endside flanges'.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find such a term. In most applications, top and bottom *need* to be treated very differently than one another (because gravity), whereas "sides" and "ends" are much more likely to be interchangeable. Think "ceiling and floor" or "roof and foundation" vs walls. Top-and-bottom symmetry is rare enough that the most common term for the two together is probably just "top and bottom".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word like "sides" that means "top or bottom"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84055/is-there-a-word-like-sides-that-means-top-or-bottom)

Comment: @1006a The first thing I thought about was the old puzzler "why does a mirror reverse an image left to right but not up and down.

Comment: This question might be better received in Maths Stack Exchange, with the tag of geogmetry.

Comment: Stepping back, why  not just call one the top and the other the bottom? Sure, top and bottom are identical, and could be interchangeable,  but for the sake of clarity why not just refer to each separately?

Comment: I guess I don't have enough "rep" to answer, but I might suggest "extremes." I'm in the same situation developing a video game and naming properties of 3 dimensional axes. I've found heave, sway, and surge ways to describe the verbs of directional movement, but it doesn't apply well when trying to describing the sides of objects. I like sides, and ends, but alas, what makes for good top/bottom? Delving into Mathematics, "extremes" or even "bounds" are sorta of relatable. At least that's what I'm going with for now.

Answer (score 2):

You want words such as "sides" and "ends" to refer to absolute directions. But your readers might not understand them like that. Often, "sides" refers to the largest-area pair of opposite surfaces, and "ends" to the smallest-area pair. For example, if something is long left to right, but narrow and thin, you might talk of its left end and right end.

In your situation if the back surface is so long compared to its width that there's no danger of the user mistaking one sort of flange for the other sort, you could describe the longer two as side flanges and the shorter two as end flanges. Not because "end" specifically means top and bottom, but because "sides" are longer than "ends".

But to judge from your diagram the back surface looks almost square to me, and I fear that a user might think of the member as having four sides/edges and needing four side flanges. I'd favour being clear even if this means using more words. For example give instructions for the bottom horizontal flange, and then say attach the top horizontal flange similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Planes, the top plane and bottom plane. Technically all the sides of a cube are planes.

Answer (score 0):

How about ‘upper and lower members’?

Answer (score 0):

> Top and Bottom can be though as the upper and the lower layer of something..

1. The top floor of the building caught fire first.
2. A ground floor is usually the bottom floor of the building.
3. Write "Happy Birthday" on the top of the cake.
4. Let us get to the bottom of that issue.

Comment: Do you have an answer to the question?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.